# BOOL and tinyint(1) ... unsigned?

Tags: mysql, boolean

i've read that the bool type in mysql is an alias of tinyint(1), therefore i should use tinyint

My question is the following:
Do i need to declare it unsigned, i mean, is it necessary ?

```
purchased tinyint(1) unsigned not null DEFAULT 0,

or

purchased tinyint(1) not null DEFAULT 0,
```

Comment: Do you have any problems with using BOOL?

Comment: _"therefore i should use tinyint"_ - Why does that follow? BOOL is perfectly fine and (in my opinion) more expressive of your intent. `TINYINT(1)` might mean "anything from 0 through 9"; `BOOL` means specifically "0 or 1" (although I suppose you could be misrepresenting your intentions :-)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not necessary; leave it signed. In fact, it doesn't matter anyway — 0 and 1 are within the range of valid values for `TINYINT` regardless of its signedness.

But, seriously, just declare it a `BOOL`, it makes it very clear that it's a true-or-false value.

Comment: i had no idea i could use bool in mysql, i though that bool was not supported in mysql....  never to late to learn...

Comment: `BOOL` is a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: Some versions might not support BOOL, also good to use tinyint because if you need to use the query in a different SQL it is easier to convert!

Answer (score 3):

It is not necssary to declare it unsigned, particularly if you're using it to store a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents.
As of today (2022-11-09) there are two answers to this question telling that it is "not necessary" to define it as unsigned. But my understanding is that it is not just "not necessary", it should be **avoided**. MySQL and MariaDB docs say that BOOLEAN is a synonym of TINYINT(1), not of TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED. And it seems that this fact is widely used by client libraries and ORMs. TINYINT(1) being read as boolean and TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED as a number.

Concrete example: https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlconnectionstringbuilder/treattinyasboolean/